# onClick is not defined MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a college registration website and I was trying to make a list where the student can choose a certain major to view all the courses in it so I made a list with all the majors and buttons infront of them but everytime i try to use  a `onClick()` function to go to another page with the courses list it says `undefined`.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Button, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Image, List } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { left } from '@popperjs/core';

export default class CreateExercise extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(e) {
        window.location = '/' + e
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {['Adolescence Education: Chemistry (7-12)',
                        'Adolescence Education: Social Studies (7-12)',
                        'Biological Sciences',
                        'Chemistry',
                        'English',
                        'History',
                        'Industrial and Labor Relations',
                        'Liberal Arts',
                        'Media and Communications',
                        'Philosophy and Religion',
                        'Politics & Economics & Law',
                        'Spanish Language',
                        'Visual Arts',
                        'Adolescence Education: Biology (7-12)',
                        'Adolescence Education: Mathematics (7-12)',
                        'Biochemistry',
                        'Business Administration',
                        'Childhood Education (1-6)',
                        'Computer & Information Science',
                        'Criminology',
                        'Finance',
                        'General Studies',
                        'Health and Society',
                        'Industrial and Labor Relations',
                        'Management Information Systems',
                        'Marketing',
                        'Mathematics',
                        'Psychology',
                        'Sociology',
                        'Special Education and Childhood Education (1-6)',
                        'Visual Arts: Electronic Media'
                    ].map(function (item) {
                        return (
                            <li key={item}>
                                {item}
                                <button type="button" type="button" onClick={onClick({ item })} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '50%' }} >Click to view courses</button>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: do it in componentWillMount hook

Comment: `onClick={onClick({ item })}` should be `onClick={()=>this.onClick(item)}`

Comment: @DanielCheung  i got TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined

Comment: @esmailsaba sorry, I deleted my comment after you've read it. Lakshya's answer was correct. The reason being `onClick` is not defined as a variable, but a property of `this`.

Comment: @Solvenc1no can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to the issue here. The first is, as others have pointed out, that you need to be calling `this.onClick()` since the click handler is a property on your `CreateExercise` class and not a variable.

```
onClick={() => this.onClick(item)}
```

The reason this alone does not fix it is because you are not actually referencing the `this` from your class. You are referencing the anonymous function used as a callback from your map, which has its own `this` and obviously not an `onClick` property:

```
{[...arrayOfCourses].map(function(item) { ... })}
```

The easiest way to remedy this is to convert to an arrow function which does not have its own `this` context but instead inherits from the scope above (your class component).

```
{[...arrayOfCourses].map((item) => { ... })}
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable) for more details on the difference between the two function expression types.

Comment: i just have another question if that's okay when it goes to the majors/ page it goes with [object%20object] instead of the name how can i fix that

Comment: Your original example is calling the method as `onClick({item})` - make sure its `onClick(item)` as in this answer. Passing `{item}` creates an object with one property called `item` which is the name of the course - this will be cast to the `[object Object]` syntax when concatenated with a string. Also, a side note, most of the strings in that array are not valid URLs (a space will usually be converted to %20) so just adding them to the window location is probably not going to generate any useable routes unless you're expecting that.

Comment: oh i did like you said but the same happens and yes i want it sent with the 20%

Comment: I really don't know why that would be. Try logging `e` in the click handler before adding it to the location and that should tell you what you have if its not the string.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is not defined as a variable, it is a property.

`onClick={onClick({ item })}` is not correct because it calls `onClick()`, but `onClick()` is not defined, `this.onClick()` is.

Use `onClick={() => this.onClick(item)}`.

Comment: it still gives me Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined when i click on the button